# Garbage collection in SML, Java, C, Pascal

Tags: java, c, garbage-collection, pascal, sml

Why is garbage collection rarely spoken about in languages such as Pascal and C, whereas it is very important in SML and Java?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pascal and C don't traditionally use garbage collections. They used manual memory management instead (`malloc`/`free` for C and `new`/`dispose` in Pascal).

Garbage collection can be *added* in most languages that don't have them, but often with considerable expenses. An example of a garbage collector for C/C++ is the [Boehm GC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boehm_garbage_collector).

Java, on the other hand, has been designed with garbage collection from the ground up.

Comment: Actually, standardpascal could be way easier to GC than C, since it e.g. doesn't allow pointer math. The most important part however is that if the runtime system can't move an allocation, your GC will be much less efficient. I assume Joachim hints on that with the "ground up" bit.

Comment: The "from the ground up" bit means that garbage collection was part of the language design right from the beginning: the language was designed to be implemented with GC. C and Pascal were designed without that idea.